# How to Implement In-app Update Google API for my current Live Application Android

Tags: java, android, google-api, publish

I would like to implement Forcefully update and flexible Update too. who did this,i.e.user receive update in-app only rather than have to check in Play store.

User receive notification or dialog for update as application version updated in Playstore.

Comment: So what is the issue? What you have tried?

Comment: do you have any idea about reference URL for that, so i can try..

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the changes mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates), and push an update then you can use the in-app update feature for later updates.